# JavaScript: Is a member defined?

Tags: javascript, hasownproperty

It seems to me that there are four different ways I can determine whether a given object (e.g. `foo`) has a given property (e.g. `bar`) defined:

1. `if (foo.hasOwnProperty(bar)) {`
2. `if ('bar' in foo) {`
3. `if (typeof foo.bar !== 'undefined') {`
4. `if (foo.bar === undefined) {`

To determine if there is a property named "`bar`" in the object `foo`, are all three of those statements equivalent? Are there any sublte semantics I don't know that makes any of these three statements different?

Comment: Worth noting that, unless someone has overwritten the global `undefined` variable, 3 can also be done as `if (foo.bar !== undefined) {`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No they are totally different. Example:

```
foo = {bar: undefined};
Object.prototype.baz = undefined;
Object.prototype.bing = "hello";
```

Then:

```
(typeof foo.bar != "undefined")  === false
('bar' in foo)                   === true
(foo.hasOwnProperty('bar'))      === true


(typeof foo.baz != "undefined")  === false
('baz' in foo)                   === true
(foo.hasOwnProperty('baz'))      === false


(typeof foo.bing != "undefined") === true
('bing' in foo)                  === true
(foo.hasOwnProperty('bing'))     === false
```

Logic-wise:

- `foo.hasOwnProperty('bar')` implies `'bar' in foo`
- `typeof foo.bar != "undefined"` implies `'bar' in foo`
- But those are the only inferences you can draw; no other implications are universally true, as the above counterexamples show.

Comment: +1 - I forgot to consider bar being on foo, but set to undefined

Answer (score 10):

These are all different:

1. `foo.hasOwnProperty('bar')` tells you whether `foo` has the property and does not perform lookup along the prototype chain.
2. `'bar' in foo` checks the prototype chain and returns true when it finds property `bar` in any object along the chain.
3. `typeof foo.bar != 'undefined'` returns true if `foo` or any object along its prototype chain has property `bar` and it's value is not `undefined`.

Here is an example that demonstrates these differences:

```
var foo1 = { 'bar1': 10, 'bar2': undefined };
function ctor() {}
ctor.prototype = foo1;
var foo2 = new ctor();
foo2.bar3 = 20;

console.log(foo2.hasOwnProperty('bar1')); // false
console.log(foo2.hasOwnProperty('bar2')); // false
console.log(foo2.hasOwnProperty('bar3')); // true
console.log(foo2.hasOwnProperty('bar4')); // false

console.log('bar1' in foo2); // true
console.log('bar2' in foo2); // true
console.log('bar3' in foo2); // true
console.log('bar4' in foo2); // false

console.log(typeof foo2.bar1 != 'undefined'); // true
console.log(typeof foo2.bar2 != 'undefined'); // false
console.log(typeof foo2.bar3 != 'undefined'); // true
console.log(typeof foo2.bar4 != 'undefined'); // false
```

Answer (score 2):

one difference is that, method 1 will check only foo object for property bar while the last two methods will also check the prototype for inherited property.

Answer (score 2):

```
'bar' in foo
```

will look anywhere up the prototype chain.  Testing to see if  `foo.bar` !== `undefined` will also return true if `bar` is anywhere in `foo`'s prototype chain, but remember if bar *is* defined on foo, and **set to** undefined, this will return false.

[hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/HasOwnProperty) is more choosy - it will only return true is `bar` is defined as a direct property of `foo`.

Per MDN

> Every object descended from Object inherits the hasOwnProperty method.
>   This method can be used to determine whether an object has the
>   specified property as a direct property of that object; unlike the in
>   operator, this method does not check down the object's prototype
>   chain.

Answer (score 2):

There are indeed some subtle differences between the various methods/keywords.

1. `foo.hasOwnProperty('bar')` returns true only if the property 'bar' is defined on the foo object itself.  Other properties, such as 'toString' will return false however since they are defined up the prototype chain.
2. The `in` keyword operator returns true if the specified property is in the specified object.  Both `'bar' in foo` and `'toString' in foo` would return true.
3. Since you are checking for the state of the property, the result will be true when bar is not defined on foo and when bar is defined but the value is set to `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

To add to what others have said, if you just want to know if a property exists and has a non-falsey value (not `undefined`, `null`, `false`, `0`, `""`, `NaN`, etc...), you can just do this:

```
if (foo.bar) {
     // code here
}
```

As long as falsey values are not interesting to you for your particular circumstance, this shortcut will tell you if the variable has been set to something useful for you or not.

If you want to know if the property exists on the object in any way, I find this the most useful, brief and readable:

```
if ('bar' in foo) {
    // code here
}
```

One can also use something similar on function arguments (again as long as a falsey value isn't something you care about):

```
function foo(bar) {
    if (bar) {
        // bar was passed and has some non-falsey value
    }
}
```