# Get items quantity in js object

Tags: javascript

I need get  js object properties count.

I search and found solutions like this:

```
var foo = {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3"};
var count = 0;
for (var k in foo) {
    if (foo.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
      ++count;
    }
}
```

Question: why needed condition `if (foo.hasOwnProperty(k)) {` ?

I think that this code must work good always, without this condition also.

I am wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8539921/javascript-is-a-member-defined hopefully helps

Comment: Just do `Object.keys(foo).length`, and add a shim for old browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some objects have properties added by the system (ie prototype).

You normally don't want to count those. The condition you ask about will make sure you only count properties belonging to your object itself.

So if you intend to make a function that will return the count for any object, its probably better to include the condition, otherwise you don't necessarily need to.

Answer (score 3):

See this: [How to efficiently count the number of keys/properties of an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126100/how-to-efficiently-count-the-number-of-keys-properties-of-an-object-in-javascrip)

yes, the hasOwnProperty method is really reduntant here.

Anyway, why you need to get properties count? I'm afraid you are solving something a bad way.

Comment: Not really redundant if you want to avoid counting inherited members.  Hopefully no one is adding members to `Object.prototype` but it does happen (including in an older version of a popular JavaScript framework).

Comment: @user1660584 `Anyway, why you need to get properties count? I'm afraid you are solving something a bad way.` --- I am obtain associative array from php to js and I need get this array count in js. Thank you, thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

It's to prevent you from counting inherited members.

If you do this (not advisable):

```
Object.prototype.x = 1;
```

Then this gives a count of 4:

```
var foo = {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3"};
var count = 0;
for (var k in foo) {
  ++count;
}
```

But with `if (foo.hasOwnProperty(k))` it still gives 3.